# Erro ao consultar base de dados local no Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#

Ao tentar realizar uma consulta a uma base de dados local no Visual Studio, retorna um exceção.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código que estou utilizando no FORM1, botão LOGIN.**

```
string sql = "(SELECT * FROM Login WHERE CNPJ ='"+textBox1.Text+"'AND senhaCorp ='"+textBox2.Text+"')";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\ThiagoSantana\source\repos\ArqX\ArqX\DBPaciente.mdf; Integrated Security = TrueconnectionString");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader reader;
con.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    if (!reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login e senha incorreta");
    }
    else
    {
        this.Hide();
        ViewPrincipal vp = new ViewPrincipal();
        vp.Show();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça de votar e aceitar a resposta caso ela tenha resolvido o seu problema.

Comment: Adicione os detalhes da exceção à pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Há um erro na sua `connection string`.
A linha

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\ThiagoSantana\source\repos\ArqX\ArqX\DBPaciente.mdf; Integrated Security = TrueconnectionString");
```

Deveria ser (note a diferença no final da linha)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\ThiagoSantana\source\repos\ArqX\ArqX\DBPaciente.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
```

Esse pode até ser um erro simples, mas há outros problemas na pergunta que você apresentou. Dentre eles, o mais grave é que vc está armazenando a senha dos usuários diretamente na base de dados sem qualquer criptografia.
Só por este trecho de código também é possível ver que há problemas na estruturação e organização do seu projeto. Recomendava ler bastante sobre o assunto e procurar mais exemplos de como organizar o seu projeto, além de como proteger dados sensíveis, como senhas.

Comment: Obrigado tvdias, fiz alteração sugerida mas o problema persiste. Instalei o Sql server management 18 e também não resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @ThiagoSantana Adicione os dados da exceção à pergunta, já que a `ConnectionString` não é então o único problema.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K8_fuAsQp07HPhRtNt7rYB5D1piIsax9

Comment: O arquivo não está público, mas vc pode editar a pergunta e adicionar a imagem pelo próprio editor.